# How do you join two tables together in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

It used to be that you could edit HTML and join your tables. I have about a hundred dynamic documents with tables that need to be joined and split routinely. Each of these tables has seven columns and up to sixty rows. Doing this cell by cell is not an option.

At the moment we are pretty much frozen. All the collaboration that depended on Google documents is no longer possible, and we are back to paper, emails, telephone calls, and are about to abandon the entire idea of Google documents as a useful tool.

How can I split and join tables? And how can I create tables that expand and contract to fit the web browser window? Tables now seem to be fixed width and almost completely inflexible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a way to merge that works pretty well for all but the most complex tables.

1. Start with your two tables.

[image: two simple tables]

2. Add a new blank row to the first table.

[image: added blank row]

3. Select the entire second table and copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

[image: second table selected]

4. Put your cursor back into the first cell of the blank row you created (**do not select** the entire row), then paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

[image: second table copied into the first]

5. Then just delete the second table.

Splitting a table would be a similar process:

1. Create a new blank table
2. Copy the rows from the original table that you want in the new table
3. Paste them into the new table
4. Delete the rows from the original table

Not as clean as a simple split/merge command, but should suffice in most cases.

Comment: It doesn't work...the entire second table is pasted into the first cell of the blank row you created.

Comment: @DianeReilly: I just tried it again and it works perfectly, just as I described. I'm using Chrome. Are you using a different browser?

Comment: Make sure that you are IN the first cell of the new row, don't SELECT the first row of the new row.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to it: You need to add as many rows in the first table as you want to copy. Then do not put the cursor in the first empty row, but highlight all the empty rows before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. The rows then get copied into a new table, instead of into a single cell.